# Rails access column data after where

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following statement in a Rails 3.2 view:

```
<% contactname = Contact.where(:user_id => @costproject.lasteditor_id).last_name %>
```

`@costproject.lasteditor_id` value is 82

There is a Contact with `user_id=82`. And Contact has a column called `last_name`

But, I get `undefined method last_name for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fabf5c6da60>`

Comment: is the colum name `last.name`

Comment: Sorry - typo - I fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this

```
Contact.find_by_user_id(@costproject.lasteditor_id).last_name
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine because you are just get the specific object you want back.

Answer (score 1):

`.where` returns a collection, so in this case you can simply use:

```
<% contactname = Contact.where(:user_id => @costproject.lasteditor_id).first.last_name %>
```